# Rspec Capybara poltergeist Element not found

Tags: rspec, capybara, poltergeist

Rspec - 3.7.1
poltergeist (1.17.0)

I have a feature test running with js: true

it fails with

```
Failure/Error:
       within(page.find('#by_category')) do
         select(category_2.name, from: 'q_category_id_eq')
       end

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find visible css "#by_category"
```

rails_heper.rb my set up is like this

```
    Capybara.default_driver = :rack_test
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
options = { js_errors: true }
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

my test

```
scenario 'they can seach books by category', js: true do
    visit root_url
    puts page.body
    within(page.find('#by_category')) do
      select(category_2.name, from: 'q_category_id_eq')
    end

    within(page.find('.category')) do
      expect(page).to have_content("#{category_2.name}")
    end
end
```

the page body results an empty page and I don't see a any javascript errors either. Category selection is done via on change AJAX call.

root to: 'books#index'

Comment: Is the `#by_category` element added to the page by JS?

Comment: Also, what does `root_url` equal?